# How to use own quicksort to decide task with several input data

Tags: java

I have a sorting task. I need to sort the participants in the olympiad game, they have the number of solved problems and the number of penalties. To do this, I need to apply the sorting algorithm I have written. The one with the higher number of solved problems is higher in the rating, but if the number of solved problems is the same, then the higher is the one with the lower penalty. If the number of solved problems and penalties are the same, then sort by name. The first number in the input example is the number of participants, the second is number of solved problems, the third is number of penalties.
Sample input:

5

alla 4 100

gena 6 1000

gosha 2 90

rita 2 90

timofey 4 80

Sample output:

gena

timofey

alla

gosha

rita

Perhaps it is possible to implement this somehow through a hashmap? There is a sorting of solved problems and sorting of penalties

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class EffectiveQuickSort {
    public static void quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> aList, Integer start, Integer end) {
        if (start == null && end == null) {
            start = 0;
            end = aList.size();
        }
        if (end - start > 1) {
            int p = partition(aList, start, end);
            quickSort(aList, start, p);
            quickSort(aList, p + 1, end);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(ArrayList<Integer> aList, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = aList.get(start);
        int i = start + 1;
        int j = end - 1;
        while (true) {
            while (i <= j && aList.get(i) <= pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (i <= j && aList.get(j) >= pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                Collections.swap(aList, i, j);
            }
            else {
                Collections.swap(aList, start, j);
                return j;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if (n < 1 || n > 100000) {
            throw new Exception("invalid n");
        }
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> participants = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> solved = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> penalty = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] human = reader.readLine().split(" ");
            ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
            scores.add(Integer.parseInt(human[1]));
            scores.add(Integer.parseInt(human[2]));
            participants.put(human[0], scores);
            solved.add(Integer.parseInt(human[1]));
            penalty.add(Integer.parseInt(human[2]));
        }

        System.out.println("solved: " + solved + ", penalty: " + penalty + ", participants: "  + participants);
        quickSort(solved, null, null);
        System.out.println("sorted solved: " + solved);

        quickSort(penalty, null, null);
        System.out.println("sorted penalty: " + penalty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a hashMap.  You need to:

- put the information in a class (or record) for each particpant.
- then create a comparator on which to sort the record.

Something like the following:

- the score is reversed so the higher comes first.
- Then if equal, the penalty is sorted so lower comes first.

```
record Participant(String getName, int getPenalty, int getScore) {
}
    
Comparator<Participant> comp =
            Comparator.comparingInt(Participant::getScore).reversed()
                    .thenComparing(Participant::getPenalty);
```

Here is how it would look using a comparator.  You will have to do some modifications to read in the data and convert to the records (or classes).

```
public class EffectiveQuickSort {
    
    record Participant(String getName, int getScore, int getPenalty) {
    }
    
    static Comparator<Participant> comp =
            Comparator.comparingInt(Participant::getScore).reversed()
                    .thenComparingInt(Participant::getPenalty);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        // list.of is immutable so add to an array list.
        List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<>(
                List.of(new Participant("alla", 4, 100),
                        new Participant("gena", 6, 1000),
                        new Participant("gosha", 2, 90),
                        new Participant("rita", 2, 90),
                        new Participant("timofey", 4, 80)));
        quickSort(participants, 0, participants.size());
        participants
                .forEach(par -> System.out.println(par.getName()));
        
    }
    
    public static void quickSort(List<Participant> aList, int start,
            int end) {
        
        if (end - start > 1) {
            int p = partition(aList, start, end);
            quickSort(aList, start, p);
            quickSort(aList, p + 1, end);
        }
    }
    
    public static int partition(List<Participant> aList, int start,
            int end) {
        Participant pivot = aList.get(start);
        int i = start + 1;
        int j = end - 1;
        while (true) {
            while (i <= j && comp.compare(aList.get(i), pivot) <= 0) {
                i++;
            }
            while (i <= j && comp.compare(aList.get(j), pivot) >= 0) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                Collections.swap(aList, i, j);
            } else {
                Collections.swap(aList, start, j);
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
gena
timofey
alla
gosha
rita
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sorting algorithm already done you're almost there. Just don't think in terms of properties like the number of solved problems just in terms of sorting participants.

To achieve that you need to change your algorithm to be able to handle comparable elements and that's what `Comparable` and `Comparator` are for (expressions like `aList.get(i) <= pivot` would then become `myComparator.compare(aList.get(i), pivot) <= 0` etc.). Then implement the comparator in a way that compares 2 elements first by number of solved problems, then penalty and finally by name (if necessary).

Here's an example of a comparator. There are more elegant ways of expressing this but I'll expand a little for clarity:

```
ParticipantComparator implements Comparator<Participant> {
  public int compare(Participant p1, Participant p2) {
    int result = p1.getNumProblemsSolved() - p2.getNumProblemsSolved();

    //result only needs to be negative (p2 is larger) or positive (p1 is larger)
    if( result != 0 ) return result;

    //equal number of problems solved, check penalty (lower is better, so we invert the calculation)

     result = p2.getPenalty() - p1.getPenalty();
     //negative: p1 has lower penalty, positive: p1 has lower penalty
     if( result != 0 ) return result;

     //if we reach this everything else is equal, now compare names

     //here we use the fact that String implements Comparable
     return p1.getName().compareTo(p1.getName());
  }
}
```

Now change your sort algorithm to sort a `Participant[]` array using `ParticipantComparator` to compare elements.